# How to hide div after form reset?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, hide, show

I'm using jquery hide, show function in my signup form. By default my div is hidden as you see from script. Also there are 2 buttons: Submit and Reset.  All works well, but there is 1 problem: it doesn't hide the divs #warr_details1  and #warr_details2  after resetting form. How can i hide them after form reset?

**UPDATE**

```
<form id="reg" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">
<fieldset>
<legend>Şirkət Haqqında</legend>
<table>
<tr><td width="270px" align="left">Şirkət: <input  placeholder="Şirkət" type="text" name="company"></td>
<td width="340px" align="right">Ünvanı: <input placeholder="Ünvanı" type="text" name="address"></td></tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>Məsul şəxs</legend>
<table>
<tr>
<td width="270px" align="left">Məsul şəxs: <input placeholder="Məsul şəxs" type="text" name="contact_name"></td>
<td width="340px" align="right">Əlaqə telefonu: <input placeholder="Əlaqə telefonu" type="tel" name="contact_phone"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend>Zəmanət</legend>
<table>
<tr><td rowspan="2">
<label for="warr">Zəmanət</label><input type="radio"  name="warr" value="1">Var 
<input type="radio" name="warr" value="0">Yoxdur
</td>
<td id="warr_details1">Verilmə tarixi (<input id="todayBox" type="checkbox"> Bugün) <input type="text" placeholder="Verilmə tarixi" id="warr_start" name="warr_start"/></td>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#todayBox").change(function() {
    var dateStr;
    if (this.checked) {
        var now = new Date();
        dateStr = now.getDate() + "." + (now.getMonth() + 1) + "." + now.getFullYear();
    } else {
        dateStr = "";
    }
    $("#warr_start").val(dateStr);
});
</script>
</tr>
<tr id="warr_details2">
<td>Neçə il müddətinə? <input type="number" min="0" name="warr_year"/></td>
</tr>
<script type="text/javascript"/>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#warr_details1").hide();
$("#warr_details2").hide();

$("input[name='warr']").click(setDisplay);
$("input[type='reset']").click(function() {
    setTimeout(setDisplay, 1);  // setDisplay after the form is reset
});

function setDisplay() {
    var val = $("input[name='warr']").val();
    if (val === '1') {
        $("#warr_details1").show();
        $("#warr_details2").show();
    } else if (val === '0' || val === '') {
        $("#warr_details1").hide();
        $("#warr_details2").hide();
    }
}
});
</script>
</table>
</fieldset>
<table>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" style="text-align:center"><input type="submit" class="button red" name="submit" value="OK" />
<input type="reset" class="button white" value="Təmizlə" /></td>
</tr>
</table>

  </form>
```

Comment: Please show how form is reset?  I don't know what that means or how you are doing it.

Comment: <input type="reset" class="button white" value="clear" />
at the end of the form

Comment: I had no idea that you were dealing with a radio button for name="warr".  I'll update my code in a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put your hiding logic into a common function that you can call from multiple places.  Then, call that function from all the places that you want it to be active, including upon a click of the reset button.  Now that I can see your HTML, something like this should work:

```
$("#warr_details1").hide();
$("#warr_details2").hide();

$("input[name='warr']").click(setDisplay);
$("input[type='reset']").click(function() {
    setTimeout(setDisplay, 1);  // setDisplay after the form is reset
});

function setDisplay() {
    var val = $("input:radio[name=warr]:checked").val();
    if (val === '1') {
        $("#warr_details1").show();
        $("#warr_details2").show();
    } else if (!val || val === '0') {
        $("#warr_details1").hide();
        $("#warr_details2").hide();
    }
}
```

And a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/5cFCb/.

Comment: I have no idea what your actual HMTL is or how it works.  Are you seeing a theme here that people can help you better if you include all relevant HTML.  In this demo, type a 1 into the edit field, then click on that field (your click handler will then be activated) and show the details.  Then, hit the reset button.  The code in the demo only runs when the reset button is hit or when the edit field is clicked in because that's how your code worked and you didn't describe a desire for anything differently.

Comment: Was working on new code.  It's in place now in my answer and in the jsFiddle.  I'm heading to sleep now.

Comment: It took me awhile to get the checkbox to work properly with jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

try delegate()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#warr_details1").hide();
$("#warr_details2").hide();
$("body").delegate("input[name='warr']", 'click', function(){

    if ($(this).val() === '1')
    {
        $("#warr_details1").show();
        $("#warr_details2").show();
    }
    if ($(this).val() === '0')
    {
       $("#warr_details1").hide();
        $("#warr_details2").hide();
    }
    if ($(this).val() === '')
    {
       $("#warr_details1").hide();
        $("#warr_details2").hide();
    }
});
});
```

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu: what does it mean? what happens?

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu: but what does happen and what should happen?

Comment: @TuralTeyyuboglu: yes. Where is your reset button?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3389/discussion-between-tural-teyyuboglu-and-genesis-)